# what method should be used?

Tags: java, networking, smtp

For finding the ip address of the smtp server in java? I cant find the right api method.

Thank you

Comment: Some context might help. Where exactly do you need the IP address as opposed the hostname? Or do you not know either one, and you're trying to figure out which SMTP server is used? (In which case, "used ***where***" is the obvious question.)

Comment: very vague question... more specifics and I'll remove DV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
```

See the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29).  However, I'm not clear why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You must ask the system administrator as this is not standardized.

A frequent scenario on Linux-machines is that the machine itself knows how to send out mail.  In that case you would use "127.0.0.1" as the SMTP host.